# Streams in parallel kernels. Writing in multiple files in ParallelDo loop in Mathematica

Tags: parallelization, kernel, streams

I need to write data in multiple files in [`ParallelDo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelDo.html) loop:

```
 Table[s[i] = OpenAppend[StringJoin["t", ToString[i], ".dat"], 
   FormatType -> OutputForm], {i, 1, 2}]

 ParallelDo[Write[s[i], i , "\t", i + 100], {i, 1, 2}]
```

This leads to errors like:

> Write::openx :  OutputStream[t1.dat,3] is not open.

Note that writing is no trouble in a normal [`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) loop. What is the way to write in multiple files in [`ParallelDo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelDo.html) ?

Comment: You are opening the file in the local kernel and trying to use the handler in the remote kernel.

Comment: `ParallelDo` opens multiple, separate subkernels. Each one of these needs to have the relevant stream open in it. In the above code you're _only_ opening the streams in the controlling kernel.

Comment: You can use `Streams[]` to list all the available streams in a kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
LaunchKernels[];

task[n_] := Module[
  {file},
  SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory];
  file = OpenAppend[StringTemplate["File``.dat"][n]];
  WriteLine[file, 
   StringTemplate["Date:`1`, Kernel:`2`, Iterator:`3`"][
    DateString[], $KernelID, n]];
  Close[file]
  ]

DistributeDefinitions[task];

ParallelDo[
 task[i], {i, 8}
 ]

SystemOpen[SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory]]

FileNames["Fil*.dat"]
(* {"File1.dat", "File2.dat", "File3.dat", "File4.dat", \
"File5.dat", "File6.dat", "File7.dat", "File8.dat"} *)
```

I'm assuming all the kernels are local so have the same `$TemporaryDirectory` in the same filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I've done a small experiment : even just defining the streams in paralleldo loop without specifying the kernel numbers also work. How is it possible? How can mathematica figures out the right kernel for a specific set of calculation ?

Comment: @KaramveerKaur It's hard to tell without seen exactly what you have done. I suggest you post **another question with all the necessary details to reproduce your experiment**. Somebody (probably me) would be happy to help there. Let's try to keep the site well organized and keep each question about a single topic. Ok? Please notice that *"moving the goalpost"* is normally [not well received](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/10397).

Comment: okee ... will do so ... :)